# How to track events of any software

Tags: windows, assembly

Softwares use libraries (sdl, wxwidgets, gtk etc.) that handle events.
as keystroke and mouse.
I have a software that when clicking on a button, an annoying noise is reproduced

how do I find the address of that button and delete the code.

for example somewhere in the software would be like this

```
if mouse_down (left)
{
playsound ("song")
}
```

I want it to be

```
if mouse_down (left)
{
null
}
```

but I need to track and find the event and eliminate its effect.
crawl I mean that the application is constantly handling events like the mouse's position, if the mouse keys are being pressed, and between that is if the button is clicked to reproduce the noise.
In addition, the software is compiled

exist a  software to track events regardless of which libraries were used to programming the software?

Comment: I'm not certain this is what you're looking for, but if using x64dbg to place a breakpoint (http://x64dbg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/ConditionalBreakpoint.html) on mouse-related functions isn't what you're looking for, then API Monitor may be of interest to you: http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor

Comment: usually much less painful is to locate the sound file and replace it with blank or empty sound ...